# Multipart form data parsing in PHP

Tags: php, forms, multipartform-data

Forgive my ignorance in this..

I think I understand that using:

```
extract($_REQUEST);
```

in a php file will convert html form inputs into a corresponding variable. For instance:

```
<input type="text"name="author"/>
```

becomes:

```
$author
```

Is that right?

However, I'm confused as to how to handle a multipart form. For instance one with 1 file (an image) and two text inputs. How do I extract this data and put it into variables?

Comment: The variable $author will be automatically available if REGISTER GLOBALS is turned ON (which is not recommended). $_REQUEST is a superglobal holding POST and GET information. I recommend you read about $_POST, $_GET and $_FILES.

Comment: @andreas: your comment deserves to be an answer

Comment: @zerkms: posting as answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after another reading, your undeerstanding of extract is right.
But note that the `author` input will generally be available as `$_REQUEST["author"]` anyway. Generally avoid to extract them all.

If you for example want the value to be reused as form input you can write:

```
<input name="author" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["author"])?>">
```

If you want to have shortnames, if for example it's too many fields and it spares lots of typing, then I'd recommend using the optional parameters to extract():

```
extract($_REQUEST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "i_");
```

This would generate a `$i_author` variable, and all other input fields with a `$i_` prefix. This is believed to have less sideeffects with other (hyopthetical) local or global variables. Also you can use `array_map("htmlspecialchars",$_REQUEST)` for extraction, if that aids the processing.

---

Multipart form data will fill up the $_FILES array *additionally*, which has a different structure. See PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 4):

The variable $author will be automatically available if REGISTER GLOBALS is turned ON (which is not recommended). $_REQUEST is a superglobal holding POST and GET information.

I recommend you read about $_POST, $_GET and $_FILES